# Change woocommerce quantity location

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm looking to change the location of the quantity input in Woocommerce. So far I've tried removing `<?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>` from woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variations.php and placing it elsewhere in a different template.

Whilst it does show the quantity input, it doesn't remove it from before the 'add to cart' area.

Does anyone know how to move this without ruining the functionality?

Answer (score -1):

Are you viewing a variation product? Else you have to check the woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php file for a "simple product" quantity input.

Comment: Thanks Niels, Yeah it's a variation product.

Comment: Still need help on this if anyone can help?